# How to destroy an object inside an attribute in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, destructor

I want to destroy an object in my code, if a certain condition is met, but am unable to do so. Can anyone please help me?
Following is the code:

```
class bank:
    name="State bank"
    no_of_user=0
    def __init__(self,name,amount):
        self.ac_name=name
        self.ac_balance=amount
        bank.no_of_user+=1
        print('Welcome')
        return
    def __del__(self):
        bank.no_of_user-=1

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if self.ac_balance>amount>0:
            self.ac_balance-=amount
            print('An amount of %d is debited from your account and current balance is %d' %(amount,self.ac_balance))
        elif self.ac_balance==amount:
            ask=input('Do you want to close your account(y/n): ')
            if ask=='y'or'Y':
                del(self)
            else:
                self.ac_balance-=amount
                print('An amount of %d is debited from your account and current balance is %d' %(amount,self.ac_balance))
        else:
            if amount==0:
                print('Enter a valid amount ')
            else:
                print('insufficient funds ')
```

Following is the output I am getting:

IN: a=bank('Asish',35000)

IN: a.withdraw(35000)

OP: Do you want to close your account(y/n): y

Now I intended the code to delete the object 'a' and reduce the 'no_of_user'. But, neither of that is happening. Moreover, even if I am giving the value of 'ask' as 'n'

IN: a.withdraw(35000)

OP: Do you want to close your account(y/n): n

The code is not reducing the account balance. Can someone please help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Most of your code is irrelevant. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You generally wouldn't try to `del(self)` as a way of removing an class instance. You've also overridden `__del__`. Why not just remove that user if they wish to close their account?

Comment: I'm afraid `del` in Python does not work the way you think it works. Calling `del(self)` inside a method will not result in suicide of the instance. In fact it is likely to have no effect outside the method scope. So the answer is you can't "destroy" the object from inside the object.

Comment: @PauloScardine , then how do I destroy the instance inside the method?

Comment: In 10 years programming in Python I can't remember overriding `__del__`. Do something else like creating an accounts property with a list of accounts and a method called "remove_account" that pops out an account from that list.

Comment: An object doesn't destroy itself; whoever holds a reference to it simply releases the reference, and if that's the last reference to the object, the garbage collector destroys it.

Comment: Python has no support for manually destroying objects.